# Update Database table from Excel file

Tags: mysql, excel

I have an excel file which contains many columns. I have two database tables - `job_new` and `job_dockets`. 
I'm trying to create an sql query that pulls two columns from the excel file (JobNo and CustManRef), and updates the field `3rdPartyRef`from the `job_new` table but only where the field `DocketNo`from the `job_dockets` is equal to the `JobNo`column from the excel file.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE your_temp_table LIKE job_new;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/cdaly/Desktop/test.csv'
INTO TABLE your_temp_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(JobNo,CustManRef); 

UPDATE job_new j
LEFT JOIN job_dockets d on d.JobID = j.ID AND j.CompanyID = 195
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.JobNo = d.DocketNo 
SET j.3rdPartRef = your_temp_table.CustManRef;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE your_temp_table;
```

The query just keeps saying 0 rows affected, so its not updating the job_new table.

So what I am trying to do is set the `3rdPartyRef` from `job_new`to the `CustManRef` from the excel where `docketno` from `job_dockets` is equal to the `JobNo` column in the excel file

Example of `job_docket`:

[image]

Example of `job_new`:

[image]

Excel file:

[image]

Ok I hope these examples make it clearer. 
So the `JobNo` from the excel file is equal to the `DocketNo` from `job_dockets`. So when the `JobNo` is equal to the `DocketNo` I then need to update the `3rdPartyRef` from `job_new` to the `CustManRef` from the excel.

Comment: Without seeing your data it is impossible to tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: And what is in the temp table?

Comment: @Shadow added screen shot from excel file to the question

Comment: 1. There is no matching jobno in the screenshot with the screenshot from job_docket table. 2. I'm not that much interested in the excel file. The temporary table is the interesting one. If sg goes amiss while importing the data, that could explain why no updates take place. 3. `j.CompanyID = 195` condition should be in the where clause, not in the join criteria.

Comment: Actually, my guess is that you import id and jobno fields from the excel file into jobno and custmanref fields of the temporary table.

Comment: @Shadow I just took a screen shot of the first few rows in the excel but the JobNo from job_docket would be in that list. The temporary table is a copy of the job_new table. I added the condition to the where but it is still not updating.

Comment: Again, you avoided looking into the temporary table. I'm sorry, but I cannot check your data for you. As stated in my previous comment, I think you import the data incorrectly.

Comment: @Shadow yes you are right. The data isn't importing from the excel into the correct fields in the temporary table. But the excel columns are an exact match to the columns in the job_new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments the root cause of the issue is:

> @Shadow yes you are right. The data isn't importing from the excel into the correct fields in the temporary table. But the excel columns are an exact match to the columns in the job_new table. – user123456789

The reason for the columns not correctly being imported is in the load data command, specifically, in the list of columns provided at the end of the command:

```
...
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(JobNo,CustManRef);
```

The JobNo,CustManRef instructs MySQL to import the 1st and 2nd column from the text file into JobNo,CustManRef columns of the target table. Based on the screenshot from the excel file, the 1st and 2nd columns are the id and jobno columns.

You should remove this cluse from the load data statement and MySQL will be able to import the data in the right fields.